# ANTLR syntax error unexpected token: plus

Tags: tree, grammar, antlr3

Hi I have a small problem in my ANTLR tree grammar. I am using ANTLRWorks 1.4. In parser grammar I have the rule like this:

```
declaration
:       'variable' IDENTIFIER ( ',' IDENTIFIER)* ':' TYPE ';'
->    ^('variable' IDENTIFIER TYPE)+
```

So I wanted one tree per each IDENTIFIER.

And in the tree grammar I left only rewrite rules:

```
declaration
:     ^('variable' IDENTIFIER TYPE)+
```

But when I check grammar I got syntax error unexpected token +. And it is this + sign at the end of the declaration rule in the tree grammar. So what I am doing wrong?

Parser grammar works fine and builds AST tree as expected. I generated lexer and parser for C# and test it for some input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing the source:

```
variable a, b, c : int;
```

you're trying to construct an AST that looks like:

```
variable variable variable
    /        |        \
   a         b         c
  /          |          \
int         int         int
```

But since `'variable'` and `TYPE` are always the same token, I see no need to create all those duplicate nodes. Why not just do:

```
declaration
  :  'variable' IDENTIFIER ( ',' IDENTIFIER)* ':' TYPE ';' 
     -> ^('variable' TYPE IDENTIFIER+)
  ;
```

which will create an AST like:

```
 variable
  / | | \
int a b  c
```

?

Comment: I tried this, and it says Decision can match input such as variable using multiple alternatives 1,2

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, (I have different errors now :) They are not connected with this..

Comment: @Vladimir, feel free to create a new question if the problem(s) you now have are unrelated to this one.