# Antlr grammar multiplicity problem of tree in tree grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have a simple grammar

```
options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  DEF;
}

root
  : ID '=' NUM (',' ID '=' NUM)* -> ^(DEF ID NUM)+     
  ;
```

and the corresponding tree grammar:

```
options {
  tokenVocab=SimpleGrammar;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

root
  : ^(DEF ID NUM)+
;
```

However antlr (v3.3) cannot compile this tree grammar I'm getting:

```
syntax error: antlr: unexpected token: +
|---> : ^(DEF ID NUM)+
```

Also it don't works if I want to create it as  `^(ROOT ^(DEF ID NUM)+)`

I want a tree that is corresponds to this (as parse creates it as well) :

```
(ROOT (DEF aa 11) (DEF bb 22) (DEF cc 33))
```

Thus antlr is capable to generate the tree in parser but not capable to parse it with tree grammar?!

Why this happens?

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844012/antlr-syntax-error-unexpected-token
its ok, that there is a workaround but, what if I want to walk a tree that looks exactly as defined above?

Comment: Well, your tree `^(DEF ID NUM)+` repeats its root `DEF` as well. So you have a tree with potentially more than 1 root, which is not possible. Could you edit your question and explain what tree you want to create?

Comment: Ok i edited it, result should be something like: (ROOT (DEF aa 11) (DEF bb 22) (DEF cc 33))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get `(ROOT (DEF aa 11) (DEF bb 22) (DEF cc 33))` you can define the following parser rules:

```
tokens {
  ROOT;
  DEF;
}

root
  : def (',' def)* -> ^(ROOT def+)
  ;

def
  :  ID '=' NUM -> ^(DEF ID NUM)
  ;
```

and then your tree grammar would contain:

```
root
  :  ^(ROOT def+)
  ;

def
  :  ^(DEF ID NUM)
  ;
```